# How can I put one treeview in multiple windows but it will have the same database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I'm currently working on my final project in school. I want to add the treeview in every new window of my main screen. However, when I try to put the code in every button, my database will crash.
[image: Main window]
[image: treeview for add item button]

This is the code below:

```
my_tree = ttk.Treeview(add_window)
                    storeName = "Add an Item"


                    def reverse(tuples):
                        new_tup = tuples[::-1]
                        return new_tup


                    def insert( id, name, price, quantity):
                        conn = sqlite3.connect("eclist1.db")
                        cursor = conn.cursor()

                        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
                        inventory(itemId TEXT, itemName TEXT, itemPrice TEXT
                                  , itemQuantity TEXT)""")

                        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO inventory VALUES ('" + str(id) +
                                       "','" + str(name) + "','" + str(price) + "','"
                                       + str(quantity) + "')")
                        conn.commit()


                    def delete(data):
                        conn = sqlite3.connect("eclist1.db")
                        cursor = conn.cursor()

                        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
                            inventory(itemId TEXT, itemName TEXT, itemPrice TEXT,
                                      itemQuantity TEXT)""")

                        cursor.execute("DELETE FROM inventory WHERE itemId = '" +
                                       str(data) + "'")
                        conn.commit()


                    def update(id, name, price, quantity,  idName):
                        conn = sqlite3.connect("eclist1.db")
                        cursor = conn.cursor()

                        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
                            inventory(itemId TEXT, itemName TEXT, itemPrice TEXT,
                                      itemQuantity TEXT)""")

                        cursor.execute("UPDATE inventory SET itemId = '" 
                                       + str(id) + "', itemName = '" 
                                       + str(name) + "', itemPrice = '" 
                                       + str(price) + "', itemQuantity = '" 
                                       + str(quantity) + "' WHERE itemId='"
                                       +str(idName)+"'")
                        conn.commit()


                    def read():
                        conn = sqlite3.connect("eclist1.db")
                        cursor = conn.cursor()

                        cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
                            inventory(itemId TEXT, itemName TEXT, itemPrice TEXT,
                                      itemQuantity TEXT)""")

                        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM inventory")
                        results = cursor.fetchall()
                        conn.commit()
                        return results


                    def insert_data():
                        itemId = str(entryId.get())
                        itemName = str(entryName.get())
                        itemPrice = str(entryPrice.get())
                        itemQuantity = str(entryQuantity.get())
                        if itemId == "" or itemName == " ":
                            print("Error Inserting Item Number")
                        if itemName == "" or itemName == " ":
                            print("Error Inserting Name")
                        if itemPrice == "" or itemPrice == " ":
                            print("Error Inserting Price")
                        if itemQuantity == "" or itemQuantity == " ":
                            print("Error Inserting Quantity")
                        else:
                            insert(str(itemId), str(itemName), str(itemPrice),
                                   str(itemQuantity))

                        for data in my_tree.get_children():
                            my_tree.delete(data)

                        for result in reverse(read()):
                            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=result, text="",
                                           values=(result), tag="orow")

                        my_tree.tag_configure('orow', background='#EEEEEE')
                        my_tree.pack()
                        my_tree.place(relx=0.09,rely=0.55)


                    def delete_data():
                        selected_item = my_tree.selection()[0]
                        deleteData = str(my_tree.item(selected_item)['values'][0])
                        delete(deleteData)

                        for data in my_tree.get_children():
                            my_tree.delete(data)

                        for result in reverse(read()):
                            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=result, text="",
                                           values=(result), tag="orow")

                        my_tree.tag_configure('orow', background='#EEEEEE')
                        my_tree.pack()
                        my_tree.place(relx=0.09,rely=0.55)

                    def update_data():
                        selected_item = my_tree.selection()[0]
                        update_name = my_tree.item(selected_item)['values'][0]
                        update(entryId.get(), entryName.get(), entryPrice.get(),
                               entryQuantity.get(), update_name)

                        for data in my_tree.get_children():
                            my_tree.delete(data)

                        for result in reverse(read()):
                            my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=result, text="",
                                           values=(result), tag="orow")

                        my_tree.tag_configure('orow', background='#EEEEEE')
                        my_tree.pack()
                        my_tree.place(relx=0.09,rely=0.55)


                    titleLabel = Label(add_window, text=storeName,
                                       font=('Roboto', 30, 'bold'), bd=2, bg='#FFC2A6')
                    titleLabel.pack()
                    titleLabel.place(relx=0.34,rely=0.1)

                    idLabel = Label(add_window, text="Item No.", font=('Roboto bold', 15),
                                    bg='#FFC2A6')
                    nameLabel = Label(add_window, text="Item Name", font=('Roboto bold', 15),
                                      bg='#FFC2A6')
                    priceLabel = Label(add_window, text="Price", font=('Roboto bold', 15),
                                       bg='#FFC2A6')
                    quantityLabel = Label(add_window, text="Quantity",
                                          font=('Roboto bold', 15), bg='#FFC2A6')
                    idLabel.pack()
                    nameLabel.pack()
                    priceLabel.pack()
                    quantityLabel.pack()
                    idLabel.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.20)
                    nameLabel.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.25)
                    priceLabel.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.30)
                    quantityLabel.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.35)

                    entryId = Entry(add_window, width=25, bd=5, font=('Roboto', 15, 'bold'))
                    entryName = Entry(add_window, width=25, bd=5, font=('Roboto', 15, 'bold'))
                    entryPrice = Entry(add_window, width=25, bd=5
                                       , font=('Roboto', 15, 'bold'))
                    entryQuantity = Entry(add_window, width=25, bd=5,
                                          font=('Roboto', 15, 'bold'))
                    entryId.pack()
                    entryName.pack()
                    entryPrice.pack()
                    entryQuantity.pack()
                    entryId.place(relx=0.31,rely=0.20)
                    entryName.place(relx=0.31,rely=0.25)
                    entryPrice.place(relx=0.31,rely=0.30)
                    entryQuantity.place(relx=0.31,rely=0.35)

                    buttonEnter = Button(
                        add_window, text="Add", padx=5, pady=5, width=5,
                        bd=3, font=('Roboto', 15), bg="#DAEAF6", command=insert_data)
                    buttonEnter.pack()
                    buttonEnter.place(relx=0.35,rely=0.44)

                    buttonUpdate = Button(
                        add_window, text="Update", padx=5, pady=5, width=5,
                        bd=3, font=('Roboto', 15), bg="#DDEDEA", command=update_data)
                    buttonUpdate.pack()
                    buttonUpdate.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.44)

                    buttonDelete = Button(
                        add_window, text="Delete", padx=5, pady=5, width=5,
                        bd=3, font=('Roboto', 15), bg="#FCE1E4", command=delete_data)
                    buttonDelete.pack()
                    buttonDelete.place(relx=0.55,rely=0.44)

                    style = ttk.Style()
                    style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=('Roboto', 15, 'bold'))

                    my_tree['columns'] = ("ID", "Name", "Price", "Quantity")
                    my_tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
                    my_tree.column("ID", anchor=W, width=100)
                    my_tree.column("Name", anchor=W, width=200)
                    my_tree.column("Price", anchor=W, width=150)
                    my_tree.column("Quantity", anchor=W, width=150)
                    my_tree.heading("ID", text="Item No.", anchor=W)
                    my_tree.heading("Name", text="Item Name", anchor=W)
                    my_tree.heading("Price", text="Price", anchor=W)
                    my_tree.heading("Quantity", text="Quantity", anchor=W)

                    for data in my_tree.get_children():
                        my_tree.delete(data)

                    for result in reverse(read()):
                        #error
                        my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=0, text="",
                                       values=(result), tag="orow")

                    my_tree.tag_configure('orow', background='#EEEEEE',
                                          font=('Roboto bold', 15))
                    my_tree.pack()
                    my_tree.place(relx=0.09,rely=0.55)
```

I expect that, whenever I click a button, it will have a new window with the treeview on it. I also apologize if my explanation is not that clear but I'm trying to explain as much as I can.

Comment: *However, when I try to put the code in every button, my database will crash* - If you're getting any error related to database please provide and I see you've opened db  connection in each methods but never closed.

Comment: Why are you using both layout `buttonUpdate.pack()`                
buttonUpdate.place(relx=0.45,rely=0.44). You have so many duplicated `pack()` and `place()`. You cannot use both layout.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I want to show the table into other buttons and I want to have the database into multiple windows as well. It's like I can't pass the code block into different windows

Comment: Hello @DirkNashOrimaco The code that you've provided, I was able to run it, but some parts of your code don't work. For example, adding items works but deleting and updating does not, so do you want to fix that? That's what you're asking in your question.

Comment: Hello again @AnkitTiwari I want to have that code into multiple windows once I press different buttons at my main window. However, when I tried to put it again to different function, it doesn't works

Comment: It's difficult to say what's your problem is I can't find *diffrent buttons* on your main window or you've not provided code related to it and there's no error so it's difficult to fix your issue

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I can't add too much code here in stack overflow. I want to pass that code to other windows as well. It's like having the same code into multiple windows. Example when I click the baking needs button, it will appear a new window and the entry box in the second picture above will appear as well. Same actions will do when I clicked the other buttons such as beverages, canned goods, etc.

Comment: Hello @DirkNashOrimaco, Understood what you're trying to say so basically you want to show your add item form when ever a perticular category is clicked and want to show data related to that category inside treeview with all the actions like add, delete and update if you can provide your code on GitHub I can help you with OG code or I'll provide you a psuedo code

Comment: @AnkitTiwari hello here's the code https://github.com/dnforimaco/Easy-Cart.git